# Is there an AppleScript I can write to remove the first instance of a character in a file name?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

In the image below, I am trying to edit every file name in the cat directory so it only contains one "." For example, I need the first file name to be cat1.jpg and so forth for all of the other file names.

Do any of you all mind providing me some guidance on how I can implement an AppleScript (with Automator?) to rename all of the files in this cat directory?

[image: Directory with filenames I am trying to edit]

Comment: Why not just use the standard rename Finder function ? it can replace text in names, in your case, replace "cat." by "cat". This rename function is available in the pop up menu button of your folder window (3rd button from right in tool bar of your screen copy).

Comment: No idea why I didn't even try to search for a replace all feature in Finder! Thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that all the files you want to rename are in a folder on your desktop named "Cat"

This following AppleScript code will remove the first instance of "." ... Leaving an empty space in its place. So, "cat.1.jpg" will be renamed to "cat 1.jpg" etc.

```
property theFolder : ((path to desktop) as text) & "Cat"
property originalFileName : missing value
property originalFileNameExtension : missing value

tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to (files of folder theFolder) as alias list

repeat with i from 1 to count of theFiles
    set thisItem to item i of theFiles
    tell application "System Events"
        set fileInfo to thisItem's properties
        set {originalFileName, originalFileNameExtension} to ¬
            {name of fileInfo, name extension of fileInfo}
    end tell

    set theOffset to offset of originalFileNameExtension in originalFileName
    set shortName to text 1 thru (theOffset - 2) of originalFileName

    set text item delimiters to "."
    set tempText to every text item of shortName
    set text item delimiters to " "
    set cleanedName to (tempText as text) & "." & originalFileNameExtension

    tell application "System Events" to set name of thisItem to cleanedName
end repeat
```

This would be a full AppleScript solution to your question.  But if this is only a one time event for you, mass renaming of the files through Finder, would be a quicker solution.

Answer (score -1):

Answering the question in the title, once you cycle through strings in a `repeat` loop, to remove the first instance of a string from a string you can:

Use `offset`:

```
set s to "foo.bar.txt"
set o to offset of "." in s
set r to (text 1 thru (o - 1) of s) & (text (o + 1) thru -1 of s)
```

Use `Applescript's Text Item Delimiters`:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set l to text items of s
set r to (item 1 of l) & (text items 2 thru -1 of l as string)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: Judging by the OP's entire post, I think it is safe to assume he is not well versed with AppleScript code.  This being the case, in my opinion, just mentioning the use of a `repeat loop` and showing code only for text item delimiters... Provides an incomplete solution.  Why not provide the code for the  `repeat loop` also? Also, your solution lacks the code to actually change the filenames.

Comment: wch, because SO is specifically not supposed to be a place where a question is: I don't really know coding, can you write me a script that will do such and such for me. If that ends up the case, the question should get pulled. The point is to encourage them to do the work. Questions without showing any code are suspect, so I was giving them the benefit of the doubt answering the only tricky part.